# NanoVNA: Smith chart units

Tags: smith-chart

I am trying to understand the units NanoVNA uses for its smith chart.

After calibration, for an "open", I see this:
[image: Open smith chart]

The units are: \$ 1000m-j71.4m \$ , where I suppose 'm' stands for mili, which does not make sense for the resistance, \$1000mΩ\$ aka \$1Ω -j0.0714\$ would look like that on a smith chart:

[image: LLsmith]

My guess is that, it means 1000Ω instead of 1000mΩ...

A second screenshot, for the 50 Ohms:
[image: 50R nanovna]

\$ 36.8m - j70.5m \$ is that \$ 36.8 mili-Ω\$? it is not even close to be in the center of the smith chart.

Reading for the "short":

[image: Short nanovna]

Units are \$ -1.013 -j31.6m \$ , resistance can't be <0.. but assuming resistance is 0 here, its pretty close to reality..

A random point with a new calibration shows a negative resistance, and I cant figure out what "\$-j688m\$ " is supposed to be, I can not math these values to a smith chart calculator to come close to that point.

[image: Random point nanoVNA]

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out!

I assumed Resistance and reactance was shown as units by default, but the default was Real/Imaginary part.

So I did not use the proper units, there is an option to change the units to \$ R + jX \$ instead of the default \$ Re + Im \$.

Under Display/FORMAT S11 (RFL)/SMITH/< List of formats shown here >

[image: NanoVNA Menu Structure Map]
[Image source](https://nanovna.com/?page_id=87)

[image: they match]